# Why was this question removed for reasons of moderation?

Tags: discussion

I usually linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252329/java-swing-using-extends-jframe-vs-calling-it-inside-of-class) to give some advice on why you should not extend `JFrame` because it's a rigid component and cannot be placed inside another one, and instead they should build their Swing GUI based on `JPanel`s. This was a good question (IMO) which had some good answers.

As I don't have 10k rep I cannot see why was it deleted, so I would like to know. This was an old question and last time I visited it I was able to see it, I'm teaching a coworker (a trainee) how to deal with arrays and he asked me why not extend `JFrame` and there were really good explanations.

Comment: *deleted by Community♦ Jan 21 at 16:00 (RemoveDeadQuestions)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was [automatically deleted as a dead question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

You are mistaken though, it was a downvoted question that has *no* answers on it, only comments. Perhaps you wanted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-the-program) which was linked as a duplicate in the comments?

Comment: Oh... My bad, I guess I'll have to delete that item from my browser's history... Thank you and sorry about that. I'll accept this answer in 12 more mins :)